# QT4, сортировка в QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, c++

Имеется столбец с числами. Берутся из файла и добавляются в таблицу посредством

```
Item->setText();
```

Если сортировать таблицу по этому столбцу, сортировка идет в порядке `1, 2, 22, 23, 3, 34, 5`... То есть по алфавиту. Нужна сортировка в порядке от меньшего к большему по значению, то есть `1, 2, 3, 5, 22, 23`... Можно ли это реализовать?

[image: То, как оно есть]

Answer (score 3):

Доброго времени суток! 
Вот в чем Ваша проблема: Вы устанавливаете у Item текст, и поэтому Qt считает, что данные текстовые и упорядочивает их лексикографически (т.е. по алфавиту). Для того чтобы это исправить необходимо указать, что модель оперирует числовыми данными, а не текстовыми.
В Вашем случае можно попробовать использовать метод `setData`:

```
item->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, value);
```

где value - число типа int.

Однако самым лучшим решением на мой взгляд является создание *собственной* модели наследника `QAbstractItemModel`.